# Notepad++: How to remove everything except url?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a textdocument with many URLs in it. The URls have many different endings like, .net, .com, .de and so on ... All the URLs have NO http:// oder www. infront. There is many other text in the document, it looks something like this:

```
2014/05/03  Red V!per       M   R   United States       jsugarcia.com/viper.gif Linux   mirror
2014/05/03  Red V!per       M   R   United States       thepeoplecenter.org/viper.gif   Linux   mirror
2014/05/03  Red V!per           R   Netherlands     ghijbeek.nl/viper.gif   Linux   mirror
2014/05/03  Red V!per       M   R   Netherlands     straalbedrijfsanders.nl/viper.gif   Linux   mirror
2014/05/03  Red V!per           R   European Union      serialnastya.com/viper.gif  Linux   mirror
2014/05/03  Red V!per       M   R   Denmark     thueringer-treppenlifte.de/vip...   Linux   mirror
2014/05/03  Red V!per           R   United States       tapitwater.com/images/viper.gif Linux   mirror
2014/05/03  Red V!per           R   Norway      sekureco.no/viper.gif   Linux   mirror
```

I want to filter in Notepad++ now so that i have only the URLs with a linebrak like this:

> site.com

Comment: What does mean `with a linebrak like this`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that all lines are terminated with `Linux mirror`, if it's allways the case, you could do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\s+([^\s/]+)\S+\s+Linux\s+mirror`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  .+        : 1 or more any character
  \s+       : 1 or more space
  (         : start group 1
    [^\s/]+ : 1 or more NON space or NON slash (The domain)
  )         : end group 1
  \S+       : 1 or more NON space
  \s+       : 1 or more space
  Linux     : literally Linux
  \s+       : 1 or more space
  mirror    : literally mirror
```

**Result for given example:**

```
jsugarcia.com
thepeoplecenter.org
ghijbeek.nl
straalbedrijfsanders.nl
serialnastya.com
thueringer-treppenlifte.de
tapitwater.com
sekureco.no
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Press `Ctrl+F` to open the search box
2. Select the option `Regular Expression`
3. Put this regex on the Find what box: `.*(\b\w+\.com).*`
4. Press the button `Find All in Current Document`

You can test the regular expression you want to on: https://regex101.com/r/0o2IsM/3

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for help <3